# Best MySQL storage engine for read heavy table with two indexes

Tags: mysql, storage-engine

I have a pretty big MySQL table (70G) with about 15 columns and 1.5M rows.
There is one index on the autoincrement id and one on a foreign key (integer). Apart from that there are several `VARCHAR` and `TEXT` fields.

The use case is as follows: The data is inserted once and then read several times (`SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE foreign_key = 1`). Every day rows that are older than 3 months are deleted.

I have thought of using `ARCHIVE` as storage engine but have read that it has many downsides and basically only one upside - saving disk space.

**What would be the preferred storage engine for this use case?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The biggest downside for `ARCHIVE` in your environment would be that it won't work.

The `ARCHIVE` storage engine *only* supports `INSERT` and `SELECT` -- not `UPDATE` or `DELETE` -- and only supports one index, on the primary key.

I would to go with InnoDB, which can, incidentally, also [store tables compressed on disk](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-compression-usage.html).  I can't think of a good reason to go any other way.

Answer (score 0):

If it's all about reading rows and there are no transactions involved and at the same time you don't really care much about loss of few rows, then Myisam is what I will suggest.

It's pretty awesome when it comes to mainly reading part.